# Show that 2 is a prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}2\right]$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

My progress:

Let's take $a \in \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}2\right]$ such that $a \mid 2$, and function $l(x) = x \bar x$.

$a \mid 2$ $\Rightarrow$ $2 = ab$ $\Rightarrow$ $l(ab) = l(a)l(b) = 4 = l(2)$

If $z \in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}2]$, then $z = x + y\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}2$, $x, y \in Z$ and $l(z) = x^2 - xy + y^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So $l(a), l(b) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus there are three possible values for $l(a)$:

1. $l(a) = 1$ and $l(b) = 4$ : $a \bar a = 1$, thus $a$ is a unit.
2. $l(a) = 4$ and $l(b) = 4$ : $b$ is a unit.
3. $l(a) = 2$ and $l(b) = 2$ : If $a =  x + y\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}2$ , $l(a) = x^2 - xy + y^2 = 2$.

If the equation $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 2$ doesn't have a solution, then $2$ is a prime. How can I show that it doesn't have a solution?

Any other proof would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $4$ and complete the square, you are looking for integer solutions to

$$(2x-y)^2 + 3y^2 = 8.$$

That constrains $\lvert y\rvert \leqslant 1$ already. $5$ isn't a square, $8$ isn't a square, so $y = \pm 1$ and $y = 0$ are also ruled out.

Another proof is: If $x^2 - xy + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, then $x\equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. For if $x\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ then $x^ - xy + y^2 \equiv 1 + y(y-1) \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, and symmetrically for $y\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. And thus, if the norm of $z = x + y \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is even, then $x$ and $y$ are even, and $z$ is a multiple of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple proof is that your equation is reduced bilinear form, and the smallest integer that reduced bilinear form represents is x's coefficient.